# Плагины для Dreambox 800HD PVR

Tags: linux

Дайте пожалуйста ссылочку на информацию как самому писать -создавать плагины для Enigma 2 на  Dreambox 800

Answer (score 1):

- [Enigma 2 development toolchain](http://www.saunalahti.fi/znark/dreambox/dm7025/enigma2_development_toolchain/)
- [The enigma2-plugin Tutorial](http://upload.sat-elita.net.pl/download.php?id=3335)